$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left(s_{n} / t_{n}\right) \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \left(s_{n+1}-s_{n}\right) / ( \left(t_{n+1}-t_{n}\right)\right)$
I am trying to solve the following problem.
Problem Suppose that $\left( s_{n} \right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of real numbers and that $\left( t_{n} \right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a strictly increasing unbounded sequence of positive numbers. Show that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left(s_{n} / t_{n}\right) \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \left(s_{n+1}-s_{n}\right) / ( \left(t_{n+1}-t_{n}\right)\right).$$
I approached it by splitting the sequence $\left( \sup \{ s_{k}/t_{k} \;| \; k \ge n \} \right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ into two cases, one where it is bounded below and one where it is not bounded below, because the sequence $\left( \sup \{ s_{k}/t_{k} \;| \; k \ge n \} \right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is decreasing. But after that I couldn't figure out how to solve it. Even the smallest hint would be very helpful.

This is the general case of the Stolz-Cesaro theorem, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/393926/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1226175/42969

I'll show that if
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_{n+1}-s_{n}}{t_{n+1}-t_{n}}<a\qquad (*)
$$
then
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_{n}}{t_{n}}<a
$$
which is sufficient for your claim.
Indeed, under (*) there exists an $N>0$ such that for all $i\ge N$
$$
s_{i+1}-s_{i}\le (t_{i+1}-t_{i})a.
$$
Fix $n>N$ and sum up this inequality for $i=N,N+1,...,n-1$ and get
$$
s_{n}-s_{N}< (t_{n}-t_{N})a
$$
yielding
$$
s_{n}< s_{N}+ (t_{n}-t_{N})a
\Longrightarrow
\frac{s_n}{t_n}< a+\frac{s_{N}}{t_n}.
$$
Since $t_n\to+\infty$, eventually $s_n/t_n<a$ as required.
